# Logging authentication failure on OpenLDAP

Tags: authentication, openldap

I need to log authentication failure on OpenLDAP. What is the proper log level bit for that? Or is there another configuration for such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication failure is logged with `err=49` - `Invalid Credential` at default `loglevel` 256 - **(0x100 stats)** stats log connections/operations/results:

```
$ grep 'err=49' -B1 /path/to/ldap.log
slapd[28269]: conn=83767 op=2 BIND dn="cn=x,ou=y,dc=z,dc=t" method=128
slapd[28269]: conn=83767 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure offhand which bit toggles this (or if it's discretely logged).
If I had to hazard a guess I would say probably 128 (ACL processing) or 256 (Stats - Connections/Operations/Results)